# trying to understand fork() behavior in c

Tags: c, recursion, printf, fork

I'm trying to understand how "fork" does work. I wrote a small program to figure it out, but the execution seems really weird to me. Indeed, "maximum final" appears several times whereas it's above the function "compute" which is recursively called. Could you explain why?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

ecrire_fils(int nb, char* name) // function to write in a file
{
    ...
}

lire_pere(int* j, char* name) // function to read a file
{
    ...
}

int max(int * tab, int debut, int fin) // find the max in an array
{
    ..

}


int tab[] = {2,4,5,4,1,2,1,2,255,125};
int seuil = 3;
int maximum;



int compute(int * tab, int debut, int fin);

int main(){

    printf("\n \n maximum final: %d", compute(tab, 0,9));

    return 0;

}


int compute(int * tab, int debut, int fin) {

    int pid1, pid2, status;
    int milieu = (fin + debut) /2;
    char name1[20] = "fic1_";
    char name2[20] = "fic2_";
    char buffer[100];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", getpid());
    strcat(name1, buffer);
    strcat(name2, buffer);

    if (fin - debut <= seuil) // recherche séquentielle du max
        return max(tab, debut, fin); // on s'arrête là et on renvoit le maximum: on n'écrit pas dans un fichier et aucun fichier ne sera lu




    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) // actions fils1, s'occupe du debut au milieu
    {
        maximum = compute(tab, debut, milieu); // on récupère la valeur du max des fils
        sleep(1);

        ecrire_fils(maximum, name1); // on écrit cette valeur dans un fichier qui sera lu par le père

    }
    else
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) // actions fils2, s'occupe du milieu à la fin
        {
            maximum = compute(tab, milieu, fin);
            sleep(1);
            // on écrit le résultat dans le fichier
            ecrire_fils(maximum, name2);


        }
        else // actions père
        {
            int j1 = 0, j2 = 0;

            waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
            lire_pere(&j1, name1);

            waitpid(pid2, &status, 0);
            lire_pere(&j2, name2);

            printf("\n fils1: %d, fils2: %d (début = %d milieu = %d fin =%d)", j1, j2, debut, milieu, fin);
            sleep(1);


            if (j1>j2)
                return j1;
            return j2;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Since the children don't seem to exit except by returning, each of three processes should print something from the print in main. You've not created an MCVE ([MCVE]) because there are incomplete functions in your code, so it is hard to know what else is going kn.

Answer (score 1):

An MCVE from your comment (with minor fixes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  printf("\n %d : pouet", getpid());
  int pid = fork();
  printf("\n %d : plop", getpid());
  if (pid >0)
    printf("\n %d : chouette", getpid());
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

A parent prints `pouet` and doesn't flush the buffer (strictly speaking, it is *partially* flushed - that's why you see just one empty line at the beginning of the output). The child inherits an exact copy of the parent, including whatever remains in the `stdout` buffer. When time comes for the child to print, this contents is printed as well.

Notice that if you change the format strings from `"\n..."` to `"...\n"`, the example would work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First there is a single process executing normally until you reach the fork call. **When fork is called, another new process is created**, which is identical in virtually every way as the original process, except for the return value of the fork function. The newly created process is called the child process, and hence the process that spawned it is referred to as the parent process.

Since you'd want to perform different tasks for each branch of the fork, it necessitates that you be able to distinguish the child process from the parent process. `fork` returns the process id (pid) of the child (the newly created process) to the parent Process

Comment: Thanks ! I thought that a son created by a fork() contained only the code after the fork() function. But it also copy the main function?

Comment: Yah, It copy and create another process, If you understand my answer then accept this.

Comment: Ok :). How can I do to execute the content of the main function only once? If I put it in a if, it's cgonna be called for each "father", because it's recursive...

Comment: I couldn't understand your question clearly, can you explain briefly?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I posted my comment too soon. If I write :                                           if (pid1 > 0 && pid2 > 0)
        compute();                                                                                          it's gonna be executed several times, right? Because I call "compute" in the "compute" function itself, and so several processes will satisfy the "if" condition (several fathers will be created).

Comment: `fork` returns the process id (pid) of the child (the newly created process) to the parent, So when the two forks completed, this `IF` condition will start to compute.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry i got confused. How can I avoid the main function to be executed by sons? I need to do a first fork in the main function, and then to test the pid ?

Comment: Yah, First you want to get the PID of the Parent then allow to that PID to execute the Main Function, Protect other PID from executing main function using `IF` conditions.

Comment: Why is the following code showing two times "pouet" ? It should appear only one time at execution right?                                                                                                                           
void main()
{
    printf("\n %d : pouet", getpid());
    int pid = fork();
    printf("\n %d : plop", getpid());
    if (pid >0)
        printf("\n %d : chouette", getpid());
}